# Dagger 2 robolectric test not compiling

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, robolectric, dagger-2

I write some tests, but dagger 2 give me errors like this:

Error:(83, 90) error: incompatible types: MembersInjector cannot be converted to Provider

Error:(92, 70) error: method create in class ArtistAdapter_MembersInjector cannot be applied to given types;
required: Provider
found: MembersInjector,Provider
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I wrote test modules and component with using Mockito

PresenterTestModule

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Model provideModel() {
    return mock(Model.class);
}

@Provides
CompositeSubscription provideCompositeSubscription() {
    return new CompositeSubscription();
}
```

ModelTestModule

```
private TestUtils testUtils;

public ModelTestModule() {
    testUtils = new TestUtils();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ApiInterface provideApiInterface() {
    return mock(ApiInterface.class);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(Const.UI_THREAD)
Scheduler provideSchedulerUI() {
    return Schedulers.immediate();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(Const.IO_THREAD)
Scheduler provideSchedulerIO() {
    return Schedulers.immediate();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
List<Artist> provideArtistList() {
    Artist[] artists = testUtils.getGson().fromJson(testUtils.readString("raw/test.json"), Artist[].class);
    return Arrays.asList(artists);
}
```

...

TestAppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ModelTestModule.class, PresenterTestModule.class, ViewTestModule.class, AppTestModule.class, UtilsTestModule.class, PicassoTestModule.class})
public interface TestComponent extends AppComponent {
    void inject(ArtistListPresenterTest presenterTest);
    void inject(ModelImplTest modelImplTest);
}
```

I don't understand why test not compiled, i'm use [this](https://github.com/andrey7mel/android-step-by-step/tree/Step_4_Unit_tests/app/src/test/java/com/andrey7mel/stepbystep) as example, but something going wrong

**UPD: the problem is solved downgrade dagger 2 version from 2.2 to 2.0**

Comment: Can you show code for `ArtistListPresenter`?